# Need to open the file in client's machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

The question is related to asp.net web site application.

Requirement 1: Need to open an excel file in clients' machine and allow the user/client to modify the 
opened excel file.

```
// After downloading file from ftp location to below path 'excelPath'
String excelPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyApp", "Excel1.xlsx");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(excelPath);
```

Output: Above code working fine with visual studio, but not working after hosting it. Also it seems the file will open in server machine but my requirement is to open it in client machine.

Note: for hosting I am using Microsoft Server 2008 R2.

Comment: `Process.Start()` will not be useful as it will make a call to server and not the client system.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access client machine's file system, but user may upload his excel file to your application. Save uploaded file in storage. Let user edit uploaded file and then download it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Process.Start as it will not work on client machine
Rather provide a link to the excel file and when the user will click on it, s/he will be prompted to open

Answer (score 0):

I used a Desktop application to fix this. Implemented a flag to check whether the user is logged in, if user is logged in downloaded the excel file and opened it, and pushing data to server periodically till the user is logged in.

This solved my requirements.

Thanks all for there helpful comments.